# Error in running the project containing .sdf file on another computer

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment, sql-server-ce

I created a c# project in Visual Studio 2010 which contains some database connectivity. The problem is when I run the project that runs correctly and when I copy the exe file and dll file and all the files from the bin/debug folder and place in another location. and deletes the project which was the c# project and try to run the exe file the form is opening correctly but when opening the database form it is erroring with this

> *The path is not valid. Check the directory for the database.
>
>   [ Path = E:\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Database1.sdf ]*

It still takes the directory which I had written in the c# code.

In the second form which is erroring with the above error i had written this code
the file path is of connection string is same which is in error. why this is happening if it takes the path from the same folder then how can i run the project on another computer?

```
     connectionString = @"E:\WindowsFormsApplication1\
    WindowsFormsApplication1\Database1.sdf";
                sqlConnection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);
                selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM table2";
                sqlConnection.Open();
                sqlDataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(selectQueryString,
 sqlConnection);
                sqlCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDataAdapter);
                dataTable = new DataTable();
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                bindingSource = new BindingSource();
                bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
```

Comment: which config file sir? i just copied all file from the debug folder and how to do what you have told?

Comment: sir how that can be done can you help me i am a newbie to c# i just started that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1**: If your project doesn't already contain an `app.config` - add one:

- In your `Solution Explorer`, go to the project
- then from the context menu choose `Add > New Item`
- go to the `General` templates and pick `Application Configuration File`

**Step 2**: put your connection string (that contains the path to your `.sdf` file) into that config file:

- open that new `app.config` file you got from step 1
- add these lines inside the `<configuration> ..... </configuration>` tags:

  ```
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="SomeNameHere" 
           connectionString="E:\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Database1.sdf"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  ```

**Step 3:** in your program, read the connection string from that config:

```
connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SomeNameHere"].ConnectionString;
```

**Step 4:** when you copy your app to a new computer, **adapt** that path in the config file as needed.

Comment: thank you sir for the explanation but "when you copy your app to a new computer, adapt that path in the config file as needed."
sir what does this means

Comment: @shariq_khan: when you copy your application to a new computer into `c:\yourapp` and you put the `.sdf` file into that directory, then you need to **manually edit** the `yourapplication.exe.config` and **change that path** accordingly, to `C:\yourapp\database1.sdf`

Comment: The connection string entry in your config file must **exactly match** the location where your `.sdf` file is located - drive, directory, filename

Comment: SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection();
            
            conn.ConnectionString =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SomeNameHere"].ConnectionString;
          sir it is erroring with configurationManager does not exists

Comment: @shariq_khan: add a reference to the `System.Configuration` assembly to your project ....